# How to change cell style to Currency

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

I want to change the number format of the Amounts column to Currency WITHOUT using .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00" as I still want the user to be able to key in a Currency Symbol (e.g. $ or USD)

I also tried using .Style = "Currency" but it gives me the Accounting style instead

Comment: If the user keys in anything that isn't their regional currency symbol, the cell contents will be text anyway.

Comment: Is it only one symbol of two or both are acceptable?

Comment: As many different symbols as the user requires!

Comment: Have the user type the currency type in a separate cell and use its content to conditionally format the numbers with the appropriate currency symbol?

Comment: @Zalyna Are you going to standardize any user input? I mean, do you want to parse the user input, transform it into double and present the value in a standard currency format?

Comment: Yes, I would want the display to be $50.22 for example